# How to add existing Entity Object, View Objects, and Application Module into a Fusion Web Application? (JDev 12.2.1 and JSF 2.2)

Tags: java, jsf, oracle-adf, jdeveloper

I have am developing a Fusion Web Application where the Entity Objects, View Objects, and Application Module are in separate JAR files imported into a View Controller Application project.

It was considered to be a way to have different layers in the application where EO, VO, AM and VC were supposed to be kept in separate JAR files.

Unfortunately, for some reason we have to bring things back into two layers 
only one for EO, VO, and AM and the other one for the View Controller project.

I just want to find a way to import XMLs for the EO and VO into the AM project so that everything could fit into two layers (ie. two jar files).

Please let me know how I can do that.

You help is much appreciate it.

Mike

Answer (score 0):

You should open the application that has the EO,VO,AM and generate an ADF library JAR from it. Then you can use that ADF library in other projects.
More info : http://docs.oracle.com/middleware/12212/adf/develop/GUID-47C4555A-E906-42D2-93E7-AB38D1A28CB6.htm#GUID-47C4555A-E906-42D2-93E7-AB38D1A28CB6